# How to persist state in a WebviewProvider?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I have an extension that renders in the sidebar.
The extension is `WebviewProvider` that resolves a `Webview`.
I need to persist state in a `Webview` but the docs only describes how to do this in a `WebviewPanel`.
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview#getstate-and-setstate

How do you persist state in a `Webview`?

Comment: In the end I used `retainContextWhenHidden`. But I would like a solution using `globalState` like https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/common-capabilities